# Many conditions in the WHERE clause of a SQL query

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Hi I'm having trouble writing a query. I will be very glad to receive some advice!

My table is called TagObjects; it has 5 columns, but the 3 important to the problem are: tob_tag, tob_object and tob_objectType.

What I need to achieve with the query is the following: with an unknown number of pairs (tob_object, tob_objectType) I need to know all the tob_tag all the pairs have in common.

I have tried with this query (the numbers are just as an example):

```
SELECT "TagsObjects"."tob_tag"
FROM "TagsObjects"
WHERE TRUE
AND ("TagsObjects"."tob_object" = 8 AND "TagsObjects"."tob_objecttype" = 1)
AND ("TagsObjects"."tob_object" = 9 AND "TagsObjects"."tob_objecttype" = 1)
GROUP BY "TagsObjects"."tob_tag";
```

The WHERE TRUE is there because I'm building the query dynamically. This query works for one pair (one AND in the WHERE clause), when I tried it with two pairs (like the example I post above) it doesn't return any rows (and the data is there!).

If someone knows what I'm doing wrong or a way to do this it will be a BIG HELP!

Using PostgreSQL 9.0.1.

Comment: Drop the TRUE; join the alternatives by OR instead of AND.

And put SQL keywords like FROM, WHERE and GROUP BY at the start of a line.

Comment: @Jonathan, You can blame me for the poor formatting.  I added line breaks (the SQL fragment was initially one line), but didn't add them in the best place.  I'll fix that now.

Comment: YOu need to use OR rather than AND in part of your query...  TRUE AND ((..) OR (..) OR (..))

Answer (score 2):

When building your optional clauses, do them using this pattern

SELECT "TagsObjects"."tob_tag"
FROM "TagsObjects"
WHERE FALSE
**OR ("TagsObjects"."tob_object" = 8 AND "TagsObjects"."tob_objecttype" = 1)**
**OR ("TagsObjects"."tob_object" = 9 AND "TagsObjects"."tob_objecttype" = 1)**
GROUP BY "TagsObjects"."tob_tag";

However, if there are no conditions at all, then add `OR TRUE` to the list, so it becomes

SELECT "TagsObjects"."tob_tag"
FROM "TagsObjects"
WHERE FALSE
**OR TRUE**
GROUP BY "TagsObjects"."tob_tag";

As for this part

> I need to know all the tob_tag all the pairs have in common.

If you only want tob_tags that have **both** 8/1 and 9/1 (or more combinations), then you need a GROUP BY and HAVING clause.

```
SELECT "TagsObjects"."tob_tag"
FROM "TagsObjects"
WHERE FALSE
OR ("TagsObjects"."tob_object" = 8 AND "TagsObjects"."tob_objecttype" = 1)
OR ("TagsObjects"."tob_object" = 9 AND "TagsObjects"."tob_objecttype" = 1)
GROUP BY "TagsObjects"."tob_tag"
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with what's wrong. You are trying to find a row where both "TagsObjects"."tob_object" = 8 and "TagsObjects"."tob_object" = 9. The "TagsObjects"."tob_object" cannot be both at the same time so no rows cannot be returned.

What you should do then?

From you specification I gather that there are several pairs of ("TagsObjects"."tob_object", "TagsObjects"."tob_objectType") where neither field is a constant. You want to create an union of all rows that are returned for each pair.

```
WITH matchingTagsObjects AS (
    SELECT "TagsObjects"."tob_tag" 
    FROM "TagsObjects" 
    WHERE ("TagsObjects"."tob_object" = 8 AND "TagsObjects"."tob_objecttype" = 1)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT "TagsObjects"."tob_tag" 
    FROM "TagsObjects" 
    WHERE ("TagsObjects"."tob_object" = 9 AND "TagsObjects"."tob_objecttype" = 1)
 )
 SELECT "TagsObjects"."tob_tag"  
 FROM matchingTagsObjects
 GROUP BY "TagsObjects"."tob_tag";
```

The named subquery matchingTgsObjects lists all tob_tags that are found for pairs (8,1) and (8,2). The actual tags are selected in the main query and distinct tob_tags are selected using the group by clause as with you solution. I used UNION ALL because the grouping is done in the main query and I didn't find any reason to prune duplicate rows in the subquery at this point. You can achieve that by leaving out the ALL from UNION ALL.

You can also include the subquery directly in the from part instead of using a named subquery.

There's also an alternative that you use OR conditions in the where clause as in WHERE (matches pair A) OR (matches pair B). A co-worker of mine would go ballistic if he saw that used: when an OR is needed to for matching in this kind of scenario it tells that there might be something to be done with actual model.

Comment: as an addendum to this - please specifically provide expected input data and what you expect the output to be.

Comment: The named subquery can be made more terse by merging the queries by either `tob_object` or `tob_objecttype`: `WHERE "TagsObjects"."tob_objecttype" = 1 AND ”TagsObjects"."tob_object" IN (8,9)`